# NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/AfterClass during annotation processing

Tags: java, maven, junit, noclassdeffounderror, sun-codemodel

I am generating code with CodeModel during annotation processing with maven. That code is for JUnit testing:

```
JMethod tearDownClass = testClass.method(
        JMod.PUBLIC | JMod.STATIC, Void.class, "tearDownClass");
tearDownClass._throws(Exception.class);
tearDownClass.annotate(AfterClass.class); <- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Yet, the compilation process throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/junit/AfterClass` when it tries to retrieve the `AfterClass.class`, which is an annotation itself.

The dependency to JUnit is defined as following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

so `AfterClass.class` should be available in my code.

How do I solve this one?

**Unclear**

The code calling codemodel is in a compiled library where junit is not a 'test' dependency. However, the code calling the generating code has the same junit dependency, but as a test dependency.

If I change that latter dependency to 'not-a-test' dependency, the issue disappears. Why do I have to define this dependency as 'not-a-test' though only the library calling codemodel is explicitely using it?

**EDIT**

Here is the dependency tree:

```
net.dwst:codegentest:jar:1.0.0
+- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile
+- org.sonatype.maven.plugin:emma-maven-plugin:jar:1.2:test
|  +- emma:emma:jar:2.0.5312:test
|  \- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:test
|     +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:test
|     |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:test
|     |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:test
|     |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:test
|     |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:test
|     +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-7:test
|     +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:test
|     \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-7:test
|        +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-6:test
|        +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.2:test
|        |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4:test
|        |  \- velocity:velocity:jar:1.4:test
|        |     \- velocity:velocity-dep:jar:1.4:test
|        \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.0-alpha-7:test
+- net.dwst:generics:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  +- org.swinglabs:swing-layout:jar:1.0.3:compile
|  \- com.sun.codemodel:codemodel:jar:2.4.1:compile
+- net.flat:flat:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  \- com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.4:compile
|     +- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:compile
|     +- org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.3:compile
|     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
|     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0-alpha-1:compile
+- org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:jar:1.7:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
|  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
|  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:runtime
|  |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.8:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-external:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
|  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-common:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
|  |  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.27:runtime
|  |  \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8:compile
\- org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:jar:2.0.3:compile
   \- org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-tools-anno:jar:1.4.0:compile
      +- org.jfrog.maven.annomojo:maven-plugin-anno:jar:1.4.0:compile
      +- org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.6:compile
      |  \- jtidy:jtidy:jar:4aug2000r7-dev:compile
      \- com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0:system
```

Very strange:

```
+- net.dwst:generics:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  +- org.swinglabs:swing-layout:jar:1.0.3:compile
|  \- com.sun.codemodel:codemodel:jar:2.4.1:compile
```

does not contain `org.junit`, yes this library's pom.xml has:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>

...
```

Comment: You understand that the problem is that the junit classes are not available on the classpath?

Comment: @Thorbjorn Yes, but it is still confusing (see the update in my question)

Comment: Did you check the dependency tree of this project? Run mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose and post the output, maybe the junit versions are different somehow.

Comment: @mtrovo Just did. I have updated my question with it. There is something strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, what you have is two libraries (A and B):

A is the code that calls codemodel. This has a dependency on junit 4.8.2 (compile scope).

B is the code that calls A (the generating code). This has a dependency on junit 4.8.2 (test scope).

B has a dependency on A, obviously.

From [Maven Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope), we have the following line,

> Each of the scopes (except for import) affects transitive dependencies
>   in different ways, as is demonstrated in the table below. If a
>   dependency is set to the scope in the left column, transitive
>   dependencies of that dependency with the scope across the top row will
>   result in a dependency in the main project with the scope listed at
>   the intersection. If no scope is listed, it means the dependency will
>   be omitted.

A transitive dependency is one that comes from a direct dependency. So library X depends upon library Y. Library Y depends upon library Z. So Z is a transitive dependency of library X.

In your case, B both directly depends upon junit (with test scope) and has a transitive dependency through A on junit (with compile scope). If we read the table, we can see that this means that the scope that takes precendence is **test**. This is why your code is failing to find AfterClass.class, because it won't be included.

Your best bet is to set the scope to compile as you have already tried.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but this the poorest choice I can imagine from maven, since it forces users to always manually add something that will always be required at runtime anyway.