# How to exclude a dependency from parent's project in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

For example, I have 2 Maven projects. One is "project-parent". The other is "project-child". Obviously, "project-child" is the sub project of "project-parent".

"project-parent" has a dependency of log4j. But I want to exclude it from the "project-child". Is there a way?

You might say I should move log4j from "project-parent" to "project-child". That is totally correct. **But the assumption is I CANNOT modify "project-parent"'s POM.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think in Maven2 there is no way to achieve this, because this is what POM inheritance is for 
.  However there is one trick that I can think of:

Assume you have the right to upload artifact to your internal artifact repository.  You may create an empty JAR, deploy it as log4j:log4j, with a obviously abnormal version (e.g. log4j:log4j:9999 ).  Add such dependency in your project-child.  Then it will override the dependency of parent to depends on a in-fact-empty JAR.

Comment: A side note: someone is doing similar thing and provided a public repository for such kind of "empty" artifacts (http://version99.qos.ch/).  They use `99-empty` as the version.  People consider the approach suggested by me may use this as convention.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know of a way of actually excluding a dependency, but you can exclude it from the target distribution, but it's a bit of a hack. You need to change the scope of the dependency to something that you can exclude in the final distribution.

So, say that my parent had a dependency on junit 4.8, in my pom you say:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So we're changing the scope to provided. For an explanation of how this works, see my answer to [NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/AfterClass during annotation processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373105/noclassdeffounderror-org-junit-afterclass-during-annotation-processing/7375380#7375380).  Unfortunately, this doesn't affect the build, but when you're copying the dependencies for the final distribution, you can use the `excludeScope` configuration element to not copy the dependency into the final distribution:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-libs</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have excluded the unwanted dependencies from distribution package, but I am using <dependencySets> in assembly.xml of Maven Assembly plugin for it. I am asking for a way to exclude unwanted dependencies from dev environment, like Eclipse. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have met the same question just like you.
In my project, let call the parent pom is parent.pom. parent defined the log4j, slf4j like this:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

child project invoke some dependency in child.pom. But I don't want the log4j-1.2.x dependency and want to increase the version of slf4j.

So. I add the dependency of parent

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifactId</artifactId>
        <version>${my parent version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and use **exclusions** to remove the **log4j**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifactId</artifactId>
        <version>${my parent version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and explicitly add the slf4j and log4j2's dependency in child pom

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

then use **mvn dependency:tree** to show the dependency list, still see the log4j

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:jar:0.8.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

well, let's add the exclusions on that dependency...remove this guy.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

then run the command again to check the dependency list. OK! clear~

Hope that can help you :>

Comment: i need to add tag type pom, like a 


<dependency>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifactId</artifactId>
        <version>${my parent version}</version>
       <type>pom</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>

Comment: most parent are pom instead of jar.  you cannot simpliy add a pom artifact in dependency tag.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, what you need is something like the following.  It pulls in a dependency and excludes that dependency from adding to its dependency list.  Often this is used if you want to inject a newer version of a package instead of the one referenced in the other package.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        ...
    </exclusions>
    ...
```

If you are instead talking about a `<parent>` relationship then I'm not sure there is a way to do this.  Can you switch from being a `<parent>` to a `<dependency>`?

Comment: I mean an inherited dependency from parent project, not transitive dependency from direct dependency as your example.  Anyway, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if you can do that.  Did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681759/is-there-anyway-to-exclude-artifacts-inherited-from-a-parent-pom

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read it. Looks like there is no way in Maven formally. I have to do kind of workaround.

Comment: What is the work around ? as I am also stuck in the same issue

Answer (score 1):

One hacky way to accomplish this is to specify the dependency in project-child but with 'test' scope (or whatever lightest-weight scope is available).  This will "hide" the scope specified in project-parent so that it is available only to test code, and unavailable to non-test code at both compile and runtime.

I came across this bug-feature mostly by mistake.  In my case, my project-child had a project-sibling with a 'compile' scope dependency, while project-parent had the same dependency specified (actually inherited from a grandparent) with 'provided' scope.  project-child was an executable however that depended on project-sibling, and so a NoClassDefFoundError was thrown at runtime from project-sibling since project-child's runtime classpath was being used, which didn't include the 'provided' dependency.  I fixed this by moving the 'compile' dependency from project-sibling to project-parent so that the 'compile' would "hide" the 'provided'.

Comment: This is a good and clean way to achieve it if lower scope level are allowed

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to exclude a transient dependency from a parent pom. By re-importing it in `<dependencymanagement>` and then setting exclusion por the dependency I wanted out. like this eg.:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. find out actual base package for your unwanted dependency

> mvn dependency:tree

Analyse this output and find out actual base package for your unwanted dependency

2. now add dependency of base package again in child pom and use exclude tag

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>base group id</groupId>
    <artifactId>base artifact id</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>your unwanted dependency group id</groupId>
            <artifactId>your unwanted dependency artifact id</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

3. check again

> mvn dependency:tree

unwanted dependency should be removed.